# Twitter Integration in ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, twitterizer

I want to integrate twitter in my ASP.Net web site, C# is my code behind language.
I want to implement a profile page in which user should be able to sign in from twitter. After clicking on "Sign Up via Twitter" Button. I have made a twitter application and i am doing this thing with OAuth. After getting user details i want to add them to my SQL Server Database(So that in future user can sign in using these details). I am using the below code

```
using Twitterizer;

string requestToken = OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken(consumer key, secret key, "Path of my localhost in which i want to call back").Token;

OAuthTokenResponse accessToken = OAuthUtility.GetAccessToken(consumer key, secret key, requestToken, txtPin.Text);

OAuthTokens tokens = new OAuthTokens();
tokens.AccessToken = accessToken.Token;
tokens.AccessTokenSecret = accessToken.TokenSecret;
tokens.ConsumerKey = consumer key of my twitter application
tokens.ConsumerSecret = consumer secret of my twitter application
screenName = accessToken.ScreenName;
userID = accessToken.UserId;
```

Now when i build the solution it build successfully, but gives an exception at runtime. The exception comes at Line # 2. The exception is

`The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.`

I have already search all around on the internet, so please answer if you have done this kind of stuff, am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: Silly question, but we wanna help you. Did you create an application inside the Twitter before?

Answer (score 1):

Between getting a request token and getting the access token, the user has to be sent to a special url (that has the request token on the querystring). Once there, the user logs in and grants your application access. It's only after they have granted you access that you can get an access token.